# multiple anchor tag href value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am creating multiple anchor tags dynamically.I wanted to get the href value of clicked anchor tag in javascript. I am using following code to do that

javascript

```
document.getElementById("aaa").href

<a id="aaa" onclick="follow(this);" href="sec/IF   00.html">Hi</a>
<a id="aaa" onclick="follow(this);" href="sec/IF   002.html">Hi</a>
```

but everytime when I am clicking on the anchor tag ,through javascript i am getting value of first anchor tag.I was thinking it will get the value of clicked element.

Is there any other way I can get the multiple dynamically generated value of href from tag.

```
   function follow(item) {

           href=document.getElementById("aaa").href;
           document.writeln(href);
}
```

Comment: ID is a unique value. You can't have several elements with the same ID

Comment: I think it would make sense to show us the definition of your `follow()` function.

Comment: BTW you should avoid space in href...

Comment: The first thing that should tip you off that something is not quite right is that you're passing the element to your `follow()` function as `item` and then not using `item` at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
function follow(item) {
    alert(item.href);
}
```

**UPDATE**

But you have to disable native link `click` triggering:

html:

```
<a onclick="follow(event, this);" href="sec/IF00.html">Hi</a>
```

javascript:

```
function follow(e, item) {
    e = e || window.event;  //IE stuff
    e.preventDefault();     //prevent link click triggering
    e.returnValue = false;  //also prevent link click triggering (old IE style)
    alert(item.href);
}
```

And you don't have to use `id` attribute at all

**UPDATE 2**

Full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function follow(e, item) {
    e = e || window.event;  //IE stuff
    e.preventDefault();     //prevent link click triggering
    e.returnValue = false;  //also prevent link click triggering (old IE style)
    alert(item.getAttribute('href'));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<a onclick="follow(event, this);" href="sec/IF00.html">Hi</a>
<a onclick="follow(event, this);" href="sec/IF002.html">Hi</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ManishSingh what browser are you using? I'm on Ubuntu and cant test it in IE, unfortunatelly

Comment: I am using chrome and IE both.

Comment: @ManishSingh Please try to use `item.getAttribute('href')` instead of `item.href`

Comment: Updated the post - now you can see full code, working in Ubuntu Chrome

Comment: I tested this code again I am getting complete url startng from the http://localhost:8081/sec/IF00.html thanks for your help this is what I was looking for working without id.

Comment: Why you have stopped the link clicking.I am asking this because I want that thing to happen.Is it possible to perform that part as well.

Comment: @ManishSingh because if I wouldn't, browser started to load a new page, and javascript wouldn't execute correctly. If you want not to stop link clicking, just omit `e.preventDefault()` and `e.returnValue = false`

Comment: @ManishSingh Or you can write `location.href = item.getAttribute('href')` in the end of `follow` function

Answer (score 0):

Ids must be unique. Set a different id to each `<a>` tags

```
<a id="aaa" onclick="follow(this);" href="sec/IF00.html">Hi</a>
<a id="bbb" onclick="follow(this);" href="sec/IF002.html">Hi</a>

document.getElementById("aaa").href  // sec/IF00.html
document.getElementById("bbb").href  // sec/IF002.html
```